# Timer job not listed in Timer Job Definitions + Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have  created a Custom Timer job which is added when a feature gets activated. The feature does get activated without any exception. But the timer job is not being listed in Timer Job definitions on Central Admin.

The same is working on Staging Server but I am facing this in Production Server.

I am working on Sharepoint2007.

Below is what I have done in **Feature Activated**.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    SPWeb parentWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
                    UpdateEmpReferralListTimer taskJob;
                    SPMinuteSchedule schedule;
                    foreach (SPJobDefinition job in parentWeb.Site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
                    {

                        if (job.Name == "xyz")
                            job.Delete();
                    }
                    parentWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
                    taskJob = new UpdateEmpReferralListTimer("xyz", parentWeb.Site.WebApplication);
                    schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
                    schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
                    schedule.EndSecond = 59;
                    taskJob.Schedule = schedule;
                    taskJob.Update();

                });
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string str = Ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
```

**Scope of Feature is "Web"**

Comment: Your question is missing code sample of what you are doing. Also please clarify what scope feature is activated (or maybe you mean installed, which would make more sence).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  Updated question with Code Snippet and Scope.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge trying to perform tasks that require administrator privilegies (like creating timer job) should not work from site level feature activation callback if SharePoint accounts set up properly. Account that web sites run under normally does not have adminstrative privilegies.

It likely works on your staging server due to all accounts having the same privileges. Check out SharePoint logs on your production server to see what exception is (after removing code that eats exception without rethrowing/reporting it - `catch (Exception Ex) {...}`).

Answer (score 0):

how do you know that your feature is getting activated without error. your code has try/catch block and you are doing nothing in catch block. if your code throwing any error, your catch block will suppress it.
add this line in your catch block and check sharepoint log.

Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("Development Debugging", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Information), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, str, null);

you can find log files in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS folder